# how can I order by column values using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing id, rate, rating category.
table

```
id     rate category
--------------------
jelly  4    c
bob    4    c
joy    4    d
ray    5    e
boy    5    d
hay    7    b
ball   6    a
```

what I want is this :

```
a        b        c        d        e
---------------------------------------
ball    hay      bob      boy      ray
x        x      jelly     joy       x
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is still the same answer, why didn't you take it the last time

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `id` VARCHAR(13),
  `rate` INTEGER,
  `category` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`id`, `rate`, `category`)
VALUES
  ('jelly', '4', 'c'),
  ('bob',    '4',    'c'),
  ('joy', '4', 'd'),
  ('ray', '5', 'e'),
  ('boy', '5', 'd'),
  ('hay', '7', 'b'),
  ('ball', '6', 'a');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MIN((CASE WHEN category ='a' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'a',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='b' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'b',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='c' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'c',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='d' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'd',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='e' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'e'
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `category` ORDER BY rate DESC, id) AS row_num
      FROM table1
 ) t1 
 GROUP BY row_num;

| a    | b   | c     | d   | e   |
| ---- | --- | ----- | --- | --- |
| ball | hay | bob   | boy | ray |
| x    | x   | jelly | joy | x   |
```

---

**Query #2** is a more flexible approach if have more tha a-e

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MIN((CASE WHEN category = "', `category`,'" THEN `id` ELSE"x" END)) AS ',category)
              ) INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `category` ORDER BY rate DESC, id) AS row_num
      FROM table1
 ) t1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY `category` ORDER BY rate DESC, id) AS row_num
      FROM table1
 )  s
                 GROUP BY s.row_num
                 ');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;


| a    | b   | c     | d   | e   |
| ---- | --- | ----- | --- | --- |
| ball | hay | bob   | boy | ray |
| x    | x   | jelly | joy | x   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9by6GKNcQfNE2NTvLywtxR/7)

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `id` VARCHAR(13),
  `rate` INTEGER,
  `category` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`id`, `rate`, `category`)
VALUES
  ('jelly', '4', 'c'),
  ('bob',    '4',    'c'),
  ('joy', '4', 'd'),
  ('ray', '5', 'e'),
  ('boy', '5', 'd'),
  ('hay', '7', 'b'),
  ('ball', '6', 'a');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT MIN((CASE WHEN category ='a' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'a',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='b' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'b',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='c' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'c',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='d' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'd',
MIN((CASE WHEN category ='e' THEN id else 'x' END)) 'e'
FROM (SELECT `id`, `rate`,
IF(`category` = @category, @row_num := @row_num +1, @row_num := 1) row_num,
@category := `category`  as 'category' 
FROM table1 , (SELECT @row_num := 0,@category := '') a
ORDER BY `category`
 ) t1 
 GROUP BY row_num;

| a    | b   | c     | d   | e   |
| ---- | --- | ----- | --- | --- |
| ball | hay | jelly | joy | ray |
| x    | x   | bob   | boy | x   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#)

Comment: I saw that it works really well on your fiddle but when I copied and pasted the same thing on my fiddle it keeps returning errors stating Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PARTITION BY category ORDER BY rate DESC, id) AS row_num FROM table1 ) ' at line 6

Comment: please show your fiddle link and i will take a look at it

Comment: I think the problem is because of the sql version difference. In 5.7 it doesn’t provide row_number function. Is there an alternative way to do the query without using row_number?

Comment: mysql 5.x has now rownumber so you have to build one see answer

Comment: It works! Thank you. It’s applicable in other versions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'a' THEN id END) as a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'b' THEN id END) as b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'c' THEN id END) as c,
       MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'd' THEN id END) as d,
       MAX(CASE WHEN category = 'e' THEN id END) as e
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY rate) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
GROUP BY seqnum;
```

Note:  This puts `NULL` in for the missing values rather than `x`.  If you really want `x`, then with your data, you can use `MIN()` and add the `ELSE 'x'`.  That won't work if any names start with `'x'`, `'y'`, or `'z'`.  There are tweaks, but they don't seem worth it, when `NULL` is a perfectively reasonable value for this purpose.

Also, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Use single quotes only for string and date constants.